# How to Create Two WkWebView

Tags: ios, ios7, swift, wkwebview

I am trying to create an iPhone app with two WKWebView, 
one for a header and one for a container. How can I create them?

I can't find any utility in Xcode/Interface Builder to create WKWebview instances. I can create a WebView which is of type UIWebView, but I can't call WkWebView methods on it and I can't conversion it to a WKWebview.

Comment: Create them through code.

Comment: but how to create two wkwebview using code in single viewcontroller. n how to give position to each one.please help
me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var item = WKWebView()
item.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,
        self.view.bounds.width, 200.)
self.view.addSubview(item)

item = WKWebView()
item.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.height-200.,
        self.view.bounds.width, 200.)
self.view.addSubview(item)
```

This code add `WKWebView` at the top and bottom of `self.view`.

Comment: var item = WKWebView()
item.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.width,self.view.bounds.height )
var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("header", ofType:".html")
var url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
var request = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
item.loadRequest(request)
self.view.addSubview(item)
     var item1 = WKWebView()
     item1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50,
     self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height)
     var url1 = NSURL(string:"http://www.kinderas.com/")
     var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url1)
     item1.loadRequest(req)
     self.view.addSubview(item1)

Comment: thanx gabbler.this is my code .when i try to run it,it shows only container not header webview

Comment: Do you mean `item1` is showed but `item` is not showed? Try to show `item` only and don't add `item1` as subview because its frame intersect with `item`'s frame, covering the header webview.

Comment: yes. but i have tried with item only for header without including container part and it is showing nothing

Comment: var item = WKWebView()
        item.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,
            self.view.bounds.width, 150)
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("header", ofType:".html") // works in simulator, works in device
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
        
        
        
        item.loadRequest(request)
        
        
        self.view.addSubview(item)

Comment: thax gabble.it is working .my problem was because of incorrect file attachment in project.

Comment: But another problem is that

Comment: I am loading website in second webview and we are using frame size to give height that is why

Comment: Some bottom part of website i cant see.so please tell me how solve height issue

Answer (score 0):

```
var item = WKWebView() 
item.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.width,self.view.bounds.height) 
var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("header", ofType:".html")
var url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!) 
var request = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
item.loadRequest(request) self.view.addSubview(item)
var item1 = WKWebView() 
item1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height) 
var url1 = NSURL(string:"kinderas.com/") 
var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url1) 
item1.loadRequest(req) 
self.view.addSubview(item1)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and why it solves the problem will improve the answer's long-term value.