# Load multiple wkwebview at the same time (iOS/Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

So my question is simple, but is it technically possible to load multiple wkwebviews at the same time,
**so all of them loads correctly?**

If I try to do it as below, some of `wkwebviews` stop loading in the middle or will not load at all (blank).
I'm not doing any UI interactions, just waiting for them to load.

Example:

```
1. [wkwebviewA loadRequest:x]
2. [wkwebviewB loadRequest:x]
3. [wkwebviewC loadRequest:x]
4. didFinishNavigation (A), no error, wkwebview loads completely
5. didFinishNavigation (B), no error, wkwebview blank
6. didFinishNavigation (C), no error, wkwebview loads partly
```

However, if I do it like this, everything works fine.

```
1. [wkwebviewA loadRequest:x]
2. didFinishNavigation (A), no error, wkwebview loads completely
3. [wkwebviewB loadRequest:x]
4. didFinishNavigation (B), no error, wkwebview loads completely
5. [wkwebviewC loadRequest:x]
6. didFinishNavigation (C), no error, wkwebview loads completely
```

**If it's technically possible to load multiple `wkwebviews` safely, then I guess it's just a bug in my app,
but please let me know.**

Comment: This answer i given few days ago,  hope it's helpful to you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59064972/10584330

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll check that.

Comment: You're Welcome...!!

Comment: Please upvote my answer so other can also view...Thank you!

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but since I'm new here, my reputation is still low and it won't show my upvote on your answer, even though it has been recored. By the way, I checked your answer, and I am adding all webviews to different super view so it won't help me. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok No problem,Thanks again...!!!